# Specify the error URL for when ClickOnce deployment fails

Tags: .net, visual-studio, clickonce

ClickOnce security causes deployment of an application to fail if the new installation location is different from the previous one. Typically, this is the message one gets:

> You cannot start the application
>    from this location because
>   it is already installed from a
>   different location.
>
> Click here to send this error to the
>   deployment server and check for known
>   solutions to this problem.

I would like to know whether it is possible to specify the URL behind the "Click here" link. I've spent many days researching this (perhaps searching for the wrong thing), unable to resolve it. The reason that it is important, is the we have different beta and producation deployment servers (and thus different installation locations). I would just like to provide users with a useful link. Note: I do want the installation to fail; I don't want to circumvent the security. Currently, if one clicks on the link, my browser will open with a tab for each word in the error summary as in the log that you get if you click on the Details... button. This is extremely annoying and not useful.

> ERROR SUMMARY
>
> Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
>
> - Activation of  resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
>
>   - You cannot start application  from this location because it is already installed from a different location.
>   - You cannot start application  from location  it is already installed from location . 
>       You can start it from location  or you can uninstall it and reinstall it from location . If you reinstall the application, be aware that you might lose any customizations that you made to the application.

Any help would be appreciated, even if it is that it is impossible. We could use an MSI installer, but there are quite a number of properties of ClickOnce that are useful to us.

I've cross posted this now here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/4629a662-e4bd-4eb9-aada-40adcaae9709.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered your question in the thread you opened in the MSDN ClickOnce Forum, which is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/4629a662-e4bd-4eb9-aada-40adcaae9709).

Comment: Can you include the actual answer here, rather than linking to an answer?